# Martian source with an IP with another MAC

Tags: networking, linux-networking

Seeing a lot of martian logs:

```
May 15 08:30:27 prd-srvr1 kernel: [789192.798073] IPv4: martian source 192.168.0.200 from 10.0.0.115, on dev eth0
May 15 08:30:27 prd-srvr1 kernel: [789192.798095] ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff 3c ef ee 4b 26 e0 08 06        ......<..K&...
```

We have two interfaces which are configured with different networks -- `eth0` in `192.x` and `eth1` in `10.x`, and default gateway is `192.168.0.1`.

The `eth1` interface is configured with NOARP.

--The best route shows as below on source host which sent packet.

```
root@prd-srvr13:~# ip route get 192.168.0.200
192.168.0.200 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.13 uid 0
    cache
```

The martian packet comes with `eth0` IP address and MAC of `eth1`.

My concern is does martian packet respond to the request made or it is being discarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does martian packet respond to the request made or it is being discarded?

That depends on your network: if you are sure that there's no routing error in your network (so packets end up on a wrong interface) you can safely discard these packets.

> The martian packet comes with eth0 IP and MAC of eth1.

That seems to indicate some problem within your network (*source* or *destination* IP / MAC?). If the traffic came from the outside, the source MAC would be that of your router/firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the martian **sender** packet shows IP of eth1 and MAC of eth0. FYI. We have only one default route. root@prd-srvr13:~# ip route get 192.168.0.200 192.168.0.200 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.13 uid 0 cache